# Using JavaScript to inject reusable content into webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sorry if this is considered too general a question. I have a website that I'm creating from scratch and without any CMS or fancy tools. I have like 20 lines of `HTML` that compose the header that is the same on every page. So it seems logical that I should use `document.write(header)` inline where the header needs to be on each page, and before that have a way of grabbing the `HTML` for the header from a local `HTML` file.

- Is this easy to do?
- If so, what functions do I need?
- Could you provide an example, assuming that the external file is called `header.html`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using AJAX - on page load, insert the contents of some URL into a DIV. The problem with this technique is that it really sucks for SEO - crawlers will see that page without the loaded content.

NEVER use document.write because it stops page execution and can only be used effectively DURING load time, not AFTER.

Comment: What function should I be using if not document.write?

Comment: This: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ You use .html() or plain old .innerHTML() to set the value in an existing DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much better/easier if you look into templating languages such as Handlebars.js.